If insulin secretion is ATP-induced, why don't fatty acids trigger insulin secretion?
I learned in my university physiology course that insulin is released by pancreatic beta-cells  in response to glucose that is metabolized and thus increase cellular ATP levels, which in turn close ATP-sensitive K+ channels. This leads to the depolarization of the cell membrane that opens voltage-dependent calcium channels, increasing intracellular calcium levels, finally inducing exocytosis of vesicule containing insulin.
So I was wondering why doesn't fat that is an energetic source and can be metabolize to give ATP doesn't trigger insulin secretion ? Is it because of the kinetics (carbohydrate metabolism may be faster and thus leading to greater ATP concentrations) ? Or are beta-cells not reliant on fat metabolism for ATP production ? Or another reason I missed ?
Thank you

Well it's also the mechanism described in Wikipedia and the first studies I could find on it. After meals, the blood sugar goes up and so does it in the pancreatic beta cells (glucose transported by GLUT2) and it's oxidized (by glycolysis and cellular respiration) and leads to increase in intracellular ATP levels. Sorry if I wasn't clear, I wasn't talking about ATP in blood. I suppose pancreatic cells can take up a bit of fatty acid and metabolize them but I don't know for sure and I don't see, if it raises cellular ATP levels enough, why it wouldn't induce insulin secretion by that mechanism.

OK. Your account of glucose stimulation of insulin release seems to be standard. The question is valid. I suspect it is to do with lack of fat metabolism in beta cells, but that needs to be checked, detailed and formulated into an answer.
